# mysql queries not adding up as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has fantasy football teams. p1 = player 1 on their team, p2 = player 2 and so on to a total of 15 players. Any player name can be in any p1-p15 depending on the way they form their team.

I'm trying to run a report on who owns what. Here is what I use to find how many people have `Will Johnson` on their team.

```
SELECT * FROM `players` 
  WHERE MATCH (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15)
  AGAINST ('Will Johnson' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND rank <= 100
```

This **returns 51**.

Then I do this code to find out how many have him in their first 11 (first 11 variables).

```
SELECT * FROM `players`
  WHERE MATCH (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11)
  AGAINST ('Will Johnson' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND rank <= 100
```

This **returns 47**.

Then I do this code to find out how many have him on their bench (last 4 variables)

```
SELECT * FROM `players`
  WHERE MATCH (p12, p13, p14, p15)
  AGAINST ('Will Johnson' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AND rank <= 100
```

This **returns 6**.

So... My problem is that 47 + 6 = 53 when it should total 51.

Any idea why or how I can fix this?

Comment: Why use fifteen fields where you could just use a `position` column? It would be a lot easier to do `WHERE position <= 11`.

Comment: You could have two 'Will Johnson's in the data.  You could have 'Will Johnson' appearing at multiple times in the line-up.  My guess is that the result is fine and the data does not meet your expectations.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins The info is scraped from another website and I just put exactly as they are into a database field. I'll be changing how it works in the future as I know it's not the most ideal way. Later I will be putting 1 row for each player.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So... You mean like leading spaces or similar? I don't see how it would return a match if it were say "Ryan Johnson".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Anujan's answer fixed it for me. It was finding "Will Johnson" and "Ryan Johnson" instead of just Will. Putting double quote sorted it in this case.

Comment: @Cully . . . That's what I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because `Will Johnson` is two words and since there's no `+` or `-` operator and defaults to `OR`, it searches for `Will` or `Johnson`.

To fix this, you should do `('"Will Johnson"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Great thanks... This is exactly it. Now I get 36 total, 3 bench and 33 in team so the numbers add up. It was picking up "Will Johnson" and "Ryan Johnson" in the same search so I obviously didn't understand how  the search worked. I appreciate it.